# JQuery text rotator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple jquery text rotator:
I have a span in which text should fade in and out.
There are similar questions here on stackoverflow but I can't apply their solutions to my situation
Here is what I wrote so far and I was wondering why this code doesn't work:

```
var i=0;
function rotate(spanid,w1,w2,w3){
  var myspan = "#"+spanid;
  var words = [w1,w2,w3];
  $(words[i]).appendTo(myspan).fadeIn(2000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
  i==words.length? i=0:i++;
  rotate(spanid,w1,w2,w3);    
  }
```

**Is the approach to the problem correct?** Why isn't this code working?
Thank you all in advance!

**EDIT**
The code isn't working as nothing is showing up.
Here is the html section relative to the function:

```
<p>Blah blah blah <span id="rotate"></span> blah blah blah </p>
<script>
$(rotate("rotate","word1","word2","word3"));
</script>
```

Comment: How is it not working? Do you have some relevant HTML code?

Comment: Nothing shows up...I'll edit the question. Thanks

Comment: Also, how and when is the function being called?

Comment: Also may I know why has my question been downvoted? Just to avoid  same mistakes next time

Comment: Not sure why it was down voted, possibly when it was only the js and not the html / edit,, SOF some times has people who down vote anything they can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, i've had a quick play and expanded it a little for you..

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4k3zfv5f/

```
    function rotate(sID,aWords, iIndex){
        $("#"+sID).html(aWords[iIndex]).fadeIn(1000, function() {   
            iIndex==(aWords.length-1)? iIndex=0:iIndex++;           
            $("#"+sID).fadeOut(1000, function() {                   
                rotate(sID,aWords,iIndex);                          
            }); 
        });
    }



    rotate("test1",["Hello", "World", "Foo"], 0);
    rotate("test3",["John", "Bob", "Billy", "Mike", "Larry"], 0);
```

**EDIT - UPDATE**

Basically there were a few corrections i had to make, so instead of going over each one.. Will just let you compare the changes.. Part of it is that the fade functions did not wait til they completed, the Delay command only applies to the jquery object and the append i reversed just for my visual sake.

Also the last part as you mentioned in the comments, was to swap appendTo with html.

**Just as an extra bonus, a shuffle example:**

JS Fiddle Showing With Shuffle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ye3rjy2v/1/

Comment: Actually it should show only one word at the time...maybe my question wasn't clear. Sorry

Comment: ahh , easy fix.. sorry you did say rotator... simply replace append with html.. i'll edit this answer

Comment: You will notice i only use 1 global variable for each span/element.. the rest is self dynamic

Comment: Yes I chose this as aswer as it's the cleanest IMHO

Comment: I've made one more change which i think you will like, replaced the first fiddle for working example.. No more variables ;) i forgot you can use a number without it being a variable. well in this case/scope.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of the append > fade > delay > fade wasn't really working. I've added a Timeout and a callback function to the fadeout to make it working nicely. Also made it easier to write the call function so you have only one extra parameter. [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/owbL4pbq/)

```
var i = 0;

function rotate(spanid, words) {
    var arrWords = words.split(',');
    var myspan = $('#' + spanid);
    i == arrWords.length-1 ? i = 0 : i++;
    myspan.text(arrWords[i]);
    myspan.fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function(){             
        myspan.fadeOut(400, function() {            
            rotate(spanid, words); 
        });
    }, 2000);
}

rotate('rotate', 'word1,word2,word3');
```

Comment: very nice! I wonder if there's a shorter way of doing it. But great answer...thanks!!

Comment: I personally must say this is not the cleanest solution, using the settimeout vs just using the callback function for the fade functions,

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    function rotate(spanid, arrayOfWords) {
        var $mySpan = $("#" + spanid);
        (function repeatRotate(index) {
            var i = index || 0;
  $mySpan.text(arrayOfWords[i]).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                i = (i === arrayOfWords.length - 1) ? 0 : ++i;
                repeatRotate(i);
            });
        })();
    }
    rotate("rotate", ["word1", "word2", "word3"]);
});
```

[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xotinimuwo/1/edit)

The above code will rotate the words defined in array after particular time interval.